# What to do when answers are in comments for question with bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

I asked a question and through the help with several comments I came to the solution. The only answer given was completely useless and I asked people to make there comments answers and the bounty is about to expire. Should I just let it go to waste?

Comment: You don't really have a choice, if no one wants to claim the bounty.

Comment: If you wish better ask the `commented person` to put it as an `answer` so that you can choice that as right answer, else no way.